# Laravel BACK PACK admin panel. Anonymous Global scopes Use

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack, global-scope

Laravel BACK PACK admin panel. i want to use Anonymous Global scopes. here is [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes). I have two tables (users , accounts_profiles)
in below screenshot you can see in accounts_profiles we have a column of user_id.

[ACCOUNT PROFILE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxJ7E.png)
[USER TABALE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnWJl.png)

first , let me explain you.
That code I do put in User Model.

```
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    $userId = 1;
    static::addGlobalScope('users', function (Builder $builder) use ($userId) {
      return  $builder->where('users.id', $userId);
    });
}
```

And that gave me that record in admin panel.( because i'm fetching only user_id "1" record)
[RECORDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmujE.png)

but now I want to join between two tables( users , accounts_profiles).
I know we will write query in User Model.

```
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    $userId = 1;
    static::addGlobalScope('users', function (Builder $builder) use ($userId) {
      return  $builder->join("accounts_profiles_biz", 'users.id', '=', 'accounts_profiles_biz.user_id');
    });
}
```

but im getting that Error.

```
response_message: [
{
code: 9997,
message: "SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous LINE 1: ...s"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = $1 ... ^ (SQL: select * from "users" inner join "accounts_profiles_biz" on "users"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = 1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1), File: D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php, Line: 669",

Exception Code: "SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous LINE 1: ...s"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = $1 ... ^ (SQL: select * from "users" inner join "accounts_profiles_biz" on "users"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = 1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1)"
}
]
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you get if try like this ```static::addGlobalScope('users', function (Builder $builder) use ($userId) {
      return  $builder->with("accounts_profile_biz");
    });```

Comment: Exception Code: "Call to undefined relationship [accounts_profile_biz] on model [App\User]."

That error produce.@EncangCutbray

Comment: Did you create model for table ```accounts_profiles_biz```

Comment: Please share your user model too

Comment: model name for user is "User"
and for  accounts_profile_biz  "AccountsProfileBiz"

Comment: Why are you trying to apply a join inside a global scope? This functionality should be configured via a [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: For what its worth, you could probably fix the Ambiguous  issue by using something like `$builder->select('"accounts_profiles_biz", 'users.id', ...// other columns etc...`.... Maybe, but this would be very odd behavior IMHO. I would just use a normal relationship and set the model's `$with` property like  `protected $with = ['account_profiles'];` etc to make it always load that relationship with the model.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from "users" inner join "accounts_profiles_biz" on "users"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = 1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1
```

[where "id"=1]  ,this id is ambiguous, check your $builder .

Eloquent ORM scope is recommended

Comment: return  $builder->where('users.id', $userId);

but when I do that , it give me right data. but that is creating problem in join.